# Can ClojureScript special forms be aliased in a way that is accessible from a REPL?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This project provides an approach to allowing users to use other human language words to replace `def` `defn` etc:
https://github.com/echeran/clj-thamil

It uses macros to wrap special forms and macros. However in ClojureScript, macros can only be evaluated at compile time. When using a browser REPL such as http://clojurescript.io/ macros are unavailable.

Is my best option to modify the ClojureScript compiler and create sets of symbols that can be recognized as special forms? My intention is to provide a batteries included learning experience for kids using their own human language. http://timothypratley.github.io/power-turtle/ translating functions is easy, but macros and special forms seem like they require compiler support?